# Protractor: OS X: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property

Tags: macos, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Just cannot get it to work on my mac.

Its been working fine on my windows machine w/t any config changes and so on but I installed it on my Mac and running out of ideas how to get it to work

Node Version: 3.10.7
Protractor Version: Version 4.0.13
Browser(s): Chrome
Operating System and Version OS X El Capitan
Installed drivers:
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
and there's chromedriver_2.25

additionally:

- downloaded from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.26/
- copied to: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
  still not working
  is there any way to set this in the conf file or something' ?

  Log:

  $ protractor conf_basic.js
  [18:34:22] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
  [18:34:22] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
  [18:34:23] E/launcher - The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
  [18:34:23] E/launcher - WebDriverError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
  at WebDriverError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
  at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:639:15)
  at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:538:13)
  at client_.send.then.response (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:472:11)
  at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
  at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
  at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)

**EDIT**

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.26
```

[07:32:45] I/update - selenium standalone: file exists /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
[07:32:45] I/update - selenium standalone: v2.53.1 up to date
[07:32:45] I/update - chromedriver: file exists /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.26mac64.zip
[07:32:45] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.26mac64.zip
**[07:32:45] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.26**
[07:32:45] I/update - chromedriver: v2.26 up to date
[07:32:47] I/update - geckodriver: file exists /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.11.1-macos.tar.gz
[07:32:47] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.11.1-macos.tar.gz
[07:32:47] I/update - geckodriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.11.1
[07:32:47] I/update - geckodriver: vv0.11.1 up to date

to gave it even more permission i went to: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium

and executed **chmod 777 chromedriver_2.26**

And I start it: **webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome 2.26** as you told me to. Still no joy

`[07:38:11] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.26 -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.11.1 -jar /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -port 4444
[07:38:11] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 509
07:38:12.779 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
07:38:12.887 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.101-b13
07:38:12.887 INFO - OS: Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64
07:38:12.965 INFO - v2.53.1, with Core v2.53.1. Built from revision a36b8b1
07:38:13.106 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
07:38:13.107 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
07:38:13.107 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
07:38:13.107 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
07:38:13.110 INFO - Driver class not found: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
07:38:13.110 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver is not registered
07:38:13.368 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
07:38:13.368 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running`

**SOLUTION**

1. **sudo** protractor cons.js    **OR**
2. download chromedriver and copy it to usr/local/bin

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are starting webdriver-manager to launch your selenium standalone server. What you'll need to do is run `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.26`. Then when starting up your selenium standalone server, you'll run `webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome 2.26`.

Comment: it's not helping, tho 2.26 is downloaded and extracted to chromedriver_2.26

Comment: If you are manually doing it, did you change the access permissions chromedriver_2.26? Also how are you starting your standalone server if you are doing all this manually?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I would suggest doing a `webdriver-manager clean`.  Then repeat the suggestion above: do a `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.26` and a `webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome 2.26`. This  would be your best bet because I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: why I had not tried that for so long -- the solution was to run protractor w/ sudo

Comment: If that is the solution then it this appears to be how you set up your node. This does not happen on my development environment. I'd suggest using something like nvm to run node / using a local node installation without requiring sudo permissions.

Comment: also got it to work w/t sudo -- only had to download chromedriver and copy it to /usr/local/bin  -- as I figured this dir was on my $PATH

Comment: What worked for me is following what @cnishina suggested above: `webdriver-manager clean`, then `webdriver-manager update`, and finally `webdriver-manager start`